# Mulit line elem text into variables

Tags: python, list, selenium

How would you make this elem.text output into different variables.
I want to be able to give each line a different variabel.
So:
Observation_date = ....
Reporting_date = ....

```
def get_lawis_data():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_info"]'))).click()
    for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="accordion-content"]'):
        print(elem.text)
get_lawis_data()
```

[This is the data I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV2LI.png)

This is the output, but in the Terminal it prints Multi Line

```
Observation date:2021-04-25 11:00
Reporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34
Name:Mustermann
e-mail:testing.test@gmail.com
Profile ID:2131
Place:Schrocken Elm Plan
Region:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen
Location:47.64627°N / 14.19269°E
Elevation:2160m
Incline:35°
Aspect:N
```

Things i have tried so far:

```
elem_list = elem.split()
elem_list = elem.split("\n")
elem_list = elem.splitlines()
```

Those gave me "Attribute Error: 'Webelement' object has no attribute 'split'"

Also thought that it might already be a list but that didn't work either:

```
Observation_date = elem[0]
```

Link to website https://www.lawis.at/profile/

**EDIT:**

Answers from below initially worked but stopped working after a day for some reason without changing any code.  Selenium is going through the page too quick and can't extract all the elements out of the Class.

Fixed this issue by adding a WebdriverWait for every element (example):

```
 lst = []
            info_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_date"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_date)
            info_reporting_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_reporting_date"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_reporting_date)
            info_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_name"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_name)
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question how many elements are being returned from find_elements_by_xpath(). Can you clarify?

Comment: @DarkKnight I added a picture of the code from the website if that helps?

Comment: possible to share the URL?

Comment: @theNishant added the url https://www.lawis.at/profile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for just printing this should help :

```
print(elem.text, '\n')
```

also,

```
elem
```

is a list in **selenium-python**.

so `Observation_date = elem[0].text`

should give you text of first element.

also, You cannot do `elem.split()` since, split method is for string not for list in python.

You can store in a list like this :

```
lst = []
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="accordion-content"]'):
        print(elem.text)
        lst.append(elem.text)

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

See

```
split()
```

is a method applicable only to text.
Since `elem` is a webElement/list_of_weblement and not a text you cannot use split() on elem directly.

Instead use `elem.text.split('\n')`